# Find all paths between two vertices (nodes)

Tags: r, graph

I'm new to the R programming and I'm involved in representing graphs using R.
I would like to ask about how I implement a code that can find all paths between two vertices or nodes based on an adjacency  matrix. I've seen many implementations in other programming languages but most of them used queues as in (BFS) to make them work. For example this is the edge list of my graph.

```
          [,1] [,2]
    [1,]    0    1
    [2,]    1    2
    [3,]    1    3
    [4,]    1    4
    [5,]    2    5
    [6,]    2    6
    [7,]    5    7
    [8,]    5    8
    [9,]    6    9
   [10,]    6   10
   [11,]    8   11
   [12,]   10   12
   [13,]   11   13
   [14,]   11   14
   [15,]   11   15
   [16,]   12   16
   [17,]   12   17
   [18,]   12   18
   [19,]   13   19
   [20,]   16   20
   [21,]   19   21
   [22,]   19   22
   [23,]   20   22
   [24,]   20   23
```

If I wanted all paths between node 0 and node 22, they should be two paths:

```
   [[1]]
    [1]  0  1  2  6 10 12 16 20 22

   [[2]]
    [1]  0  1  2  5  8 11 13 19 22
```

Thanks

Comment: By path, do you mean paths with no repeated vertices?  Otherwise in your example you'd have infinitely many since there's a loop.

Comment: I just wanted to find all paths between any given two vertices. The example is a directed graphs with no cycles.

Answer (score 5):

I have used the following code to **create a matrix** (vertices x vertices) **that contains the number of all paths between every two vertices**.

```
library(igraph)
setwd("C:/Workspace")
graph <- read.graph("graph.txt", format="edgelist")
direct <- get.adjacency(graph)
indirect <- direct
max <- vcount(graph)-1
for(i in 0:max)
 for(j in 0:max)
  indirect[i,j] <- length(get.all.shortest.paths(graph, from=i, to=j, mode="out"))
```

I propose to use the igraph library for this purpose.

```
library(igraph)
```

I have put your edge list into a file called "graph.txt" which i put into "C:\workspace". Then I use the following code to read-in that file in R:

```
setwd("C:/Workspace")
graph <- read.graph("graph.txt", format="edgelist")
```

You might want to plot the graph just to be sure that everything 's alright (however, this step can be left away):

```
plot(graph, layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold.grid)
```

I create a adjacency-matrix to see all direct links between the vertices:

```
direct <- get.adjacency(graph)
```

Then I create a dummy matrix called "indirect" wich is a copy of the adjancency matrix. I just need this matrix to later fill it with the indirect values:

```
indirect <- direct
```

Finally, I iterate over the whole graph to find the number of all indirect connections between every two vertices. I put this number into the indirect-matrix that I have just created before (additionally I have created a clause putting all values on the diagonal zero). Mode "out" ensures that only outgoing paths are counted. This can also be set to "in" or "total":

```
max <- vcount(graph)-1
for(i in 0:max)
 for(j in 0:max)
   indirect[i,j] <- length(get.all.shortest.paths(graph, from=i, to=j, mode="out"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have a simple [directed acyclic graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (DAG), the following approach will work for counting:

`(A^n)_ij` gives you the number of paths of length `n` between nodes `i` and `j`.  Therefore you need to compute `A + A^2 + ... + A^n + ...` to get the total number of paths between any two nodes.  It is essential that you work with a DAG, as this guarantees that for large enough `n`, `A^n = 0`.  Then the result can be written as `A . (I - A)^(-1)` where `I` is the identity matrix.

---

**EDIT:**

I don't really know R so I can only give you some pseudocode or explanations.

First, **let's find the set of nodes reachable from node `i`**.  Let's define vector `v` to contain only zeros except at the `i`th position where it contains 1.  E.g. for the 1st node you'll have

```
v = (1,0,0, ..., 0)
```

Now let `v_(n+1) = sign(v_n + A . v_n)`, where the purpose of the `sign()` function is to replace nonzero elements by 1 and keep zeros 0.  Do this iteration until you reach the fixed point, and you'll have a vector `v` with nonzero elements at the positions corresponding to the nodes reachable from node `i`.

If instead of the vector `v` you start with the identity matrix (of the same size as `A`), you'll get the reachable nodes for each other node in one go.

Now you have the set of reachable nodes for any starting node.  Similarly you can get the list of nodes from which any target node is reachable (just reverse the directed edges, i.e. transpose `A`)

Next, **let's traverse the graph and find all paths you need**.

This recursive function should do it (pseudocode):

```
traverse( path-so-far, target ):
    let S = the last element of path-so-far
    if S == target:
        output path-so-far
        return
    let N = the set of nodes reachable from S in one step
    remove all nodes from N from which the target is not reachable
    for each K in N:
       traverse( append(path-so-far, K), target )
```

`path-so-far` is the list of nodes already visited; `target` is the target node.

For a given pair of start and target nodes, just do `traverse( {start}, target )`.

Note that the step where we remove all nodes from which the target is not reachable is only there to speed up the traversal, and don't enter "blind alleys"

Comment: I actually need to find all paths themselves (not counting all paths). I found some implementation in other languages that used queues to determine what nodes are already visited and so on. Could you please explain more how to do it by traversing the graph recursively in all possible ways. I might need to use it for large graphs.

Comment: @malhom I updated my answer.  Please accept if it is useful for you.

Comment: Can you please explain what is the meaning of target is not reachable. do you mean not reachable in 1 step or something else, do you have non-recursive method for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following igraph function out:

http://igraph.org/r/doc/all_simple_paths.html

It list all simple paths from one source.

Description
This function lists are simple paths from one source vertex to another vertex or vertices. A path is simple if the vertices it visits are not visited more than once.

Usage
all_simple_paths(graph, from, to = V(graph), mode = c("out", "in", "all",
  "total"))

Arguments

graph
The input graph.

from
The source vertex.

to
The target vertex of vertices. Defaults to all vertices.

mode
Character constant, gives whether the shortest paths to or from the given vertices should be calculated for directed graphs. If out then the shortest paths from the vertex, if in then to it will be considered. If all, the default, then the corresponding undirected graph will be used, ie. not directed paths are searched. This argument is ignored for undirected graphs.

Details

Note that potentially there are exponentially many paths between two vertices of a graph, and you may run out of memory when using this function, if your graph is lattice-like.

This function currently ignored multiple and loop edges.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a good read of the graphical models task view:

http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/cran.r-project.org/web/views/gR.html

Although I don't thing what you are doing is graphical modelling in a statistical sense, this task view outlines packages for graph handling and algorithms.

I've used igraph for various graphy things.

Comment: I've seen and worked a little on the igraph package. I could only find the (get.all.shortest.paths). I might need to implement the (DFS algorithm) to give me all paths between any given two vertices.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a depth first search without checking the nodes visited - this can give you the number of paths between two points of a specific length

```
void dfs(int start, int hops)
{
  if(hops == k && start == t)
    {
      path++;
      return;
    }
  else if(hops >= k)
    return;
  for(int w = 1; w <= n; w++)
    if(routes[start][w])
      dfs(w, hops + 1);
}
```

And in main, call

```
dfs(start_node, length);
```

How do you do if there are multiple paths connecting two points, and each is considered to be different?